# Android programmatically added ConstraintLayout isn't shown on screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-9.0-pie

I'm trying to create a layout draw of a system, which is very similar to a table, therefore, I try to create a constraint layout with rows and columns (which I may need to connect with lines, therefore, vertical/horizontal layouts are not best suited for it).

Also, since the system is of different sizes known only at *runtime*, I must draw the layout programmatically.

I have a problem with constructing such a ConstraintLayout - even though I have added all elements to the layout, it doesn't render them on the screen.

I'm using Android Pie (API level 28, creating it for very specific devices using it), with Java 8.

I have followed the instructions given in the following articles:

1. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/04/08/constraintlayout-chaining-views-programmatically/
2. https://www.zoftino.com/adding-views-&-constraints-to-android-constraint-layout-programmatically

Attaching simplified version of my code (which still doesn't work).

The code does the following:

1. Create some mockup data
2. For each row:

   2.1. Creates and adds buttons according to the numbers in the row to the **general** layout

   2.2. Connect the buttons using the **general** *ConstrainSet*

   2.3. Create a chain out of the buttons in the current row (since I want these to be in the same elevation)

   2.4. Connect the buttom number 0 to the previous row (or to the top of the screen, these are the "centers" of each row)

And the code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String logTag = "Main Test";
    private final static int    NUM_OF_ROWS = 5;

    private List<List<Integer>> mLayoutNums;
    private ConstraintLayout mScreenLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mScreenLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        createMockupData();

        drawBuildingLayout();
    }

    private void createMockupData() {
        mLayoutNums = new ArrayList<>(NUM_OF_ROWS);
        /*
            The output should be as follows:

            [2, 0, 1, 3]
               [0]
               [0, 1]
            [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
               [0, 1, 2]
         */
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 2, 3, 4));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 1, 3));
    }

    private void drawBuildingLayout() {
        ConstraintSet conSet = new ConstraintSet();
        conSet.clone(mScreenLayout);

        int[] centerIds = new int[NUM_OF_ROWS];

        for (int row = NUM_OF_ROWS - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
            List<Integer> numsInRow = mLayoutNums.get(row);
            addSingleRow(row, numsInRow, conSet, centerIds);
        }

        // connect last row to the bottom
        conSet.connect(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                       centerIds[0],
                       ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

        conSet.createVerticalChain(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                   ConstraintSet.TOP,
                                   ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                   ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                   centerIds,
                                   null,
                                   ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);

        conSet.applyTo(mScreenLayout);
        Log.i(logTag, "the screen should be shown now: " + mScreenLayout.isShown());
    }

    private void addSingleRow(int row,
                              List<Integer> numsInRow,
                              ConstraintSet conSet,
                              int[] centerIds) {
        if (numsInRow.size() > 1) {
            addMultipleNumsRow(row, numsInRow, conSet, centerIds);
        }
        else if (numsInRow.size() == 1){
            addSingleNumRow(row, numsInRow.get(0), conSet, centerIds);
        }
    }

    private void connectToPrevRow(int row, ConstraintSet conSet, int[] centerIds) {
        if (row < NUM_OF_ROWS - 1) {
            conSet.connect(centerIds[row + 1],
                           ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                           centerIds[row],
                           ConstraintSet.TOP);
        } else if (row == NUM_OF_ROWS - 1) {
            conSet.connect(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                           ConstraintSet.TOP,
                           centerIds[row],
                           ConstraintSet.TOP);
        }
    }

    private void connectAndChainRow(int[] rowButtonIds,
                                    ConstraintSet conSet) {
        // First button will be attached to the left side of the parent
        int leftNeighborId = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        int leftNeighborSide = ConstraintSet.LEFT;

        for (int col = 0; col < rowButtonIds.length; ++col) {
            conSet.connect(leftNeighborId,
                           leftNeighborSide,
                           rowButtonIds[col],
                           ConstraintSet.LEFT);

            leftNeighborId = rowButtonIds[col];
            leftNeighborSide = ConstraintSet.RIGHT;
        }

        // Connecting to the right side of the parent
        conSet.connect(leftNeighborId,
                       leftNeighborSide,
                       ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

        conSet.createHorizontalChain(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                     ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                     ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                     ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                     rowButtonIds,
                                     null,
                                     ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);
    }

    private void addMultipleNumsRow(int row,
                                    List<Integer> numsInRow,
                                    ConstraintSet conSet,
                                    int[] centerIds) {
        int[] buttonsIds = new int[numsInRow.size()];

        for (int pos = 0; pos < numsInRow.size(); ++pos) {
            int col = numsInRow.get(pos);
            Button button = createButton(row, col);

            button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            int currButtonId = button.getId();
            buttonsIds[pos] = currButtonId;
            mScreenLayout.addView(button);

            if (pos == 0) {
                centerIds[row] = currButtonId;
            }
        }

        connectAndChainRow(buttonsIds, conSet);

        connectToPrevRow(row, conSet, centerIds);

        Log.i(logTag, "Created constrain chain and buttons for row: "
                      + row + " number of columns: "
                      + numsInRow.size());
    }

    private void addSingleNumRow(int row,
                                 int num,
                                 ConstraintSet conSet,
                                 int[] centerIds) {
        Button button = createButton(row, num);
        button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mScreenLayout.addView(button);

        centerIds[row] = button.getId();

        conSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        conSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

        connectToPrevRow(row, conSet, centerIds);
    }

    private Button createButton(int row, int col) {
        Button resButton = new Button(this);

        resButton.setTextAlignment(Button.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        resButton.setText(String.format("(%d, %d)", row, col));

        resButton.setId(View.generateViewId());

        return resButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are cloning the *ConstraintSet* before adding your views. As a result, the view ids don't appear in the *ConstraintSet* and can't be connected.

Try moving the following line to after the for loop.

```
conSet.clone(mScreenLayout);
```

This probably won't solve all the issues, but it will help get you started.

Btw, if you don't already know about it, the "Layout Inspector" (Tools->Layout Inspector) is a good way to get a look at your layout from an emulator or device.

Answer (score 0):

There a few issues that I have found at the code.

The first is the bug [Cheticamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287910/cheticamp) have pointed out. I need to call the ConstraintSet.clone() function only **after** I have already added *all* of the buttons to the layout.

However, after I had changed the order, I still got all of the buttons in one line, at the top of the screen. In order to fix this, I had to add another constraint to all of the buttons - for each button in row *R*, connect the *bottom* it to the *bottom* of the center button in that row, so all will align in the same row.

That has solved my major issues in this code!

Here is my fully working code (for others to reference, if needed):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String logTag = "Main Test";
    private final static int    NUM_OF_ROWS = 5;

    private List<List<Integer>> mLayoutNums;
    private int[][]             mButtonIds;
    private ConstraintLayout    mScreenLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mScreenLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        mButtonIds = new int[NUM_OF_ROWS][];

        createMockupData();

        drawBuildingLayout();
    }

    private void createMockupData() {
        mLayoutNums = new ArrayList<>(NUM_OF_ROWS);
        /*
            The output should be as follows:

            [2, 0, 1, 3]
               [0]
               [0, 1]
            [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
               [0, 1, 2]

            Total: 15 stations
         */
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 2, 3, 4));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0, 1));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(0));
        mLayoutNums.add(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 1, 3));
    }

    private void drawBuildingLayout() {
        ConstraintSet conSet = new ConstraintSet();


        int[] centerIds = new int[NUM_OF_ROWS];

        for (int row = NUM_OF_ROWS - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
            List<Integer> numsInRow = mLayoutNums.get(row);
            addSingleRow(row, numsInRow, centerIds);
        }

        conSet.clone(mScreenLayout);

        for (int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS; ++row) {
            if (mButtonIds[row].length > 1) {
                connectAndChainRow(mButtonIds[row], centerIds[row], conSet);
            } else {
                conSet.centerHorizontally(centerIds[row], ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
            }
        }

        connectRows(conSet, centerIds);

        conSet.createVerticalChain(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                   ConstraintSet.TOP,
                                   ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                   ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                   centerIds,
                                   null,
                                   ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);

        conSet.applyTo(mScreenLayout);
        Log.i(logTag, "the screen should be shown now: " + mScreenLayout.isShown());
    }

    private void addSingleRow(int row,
                              List<Integer> numsInRow,
                              int[] centerIds) {
        if (numsInRow.size() > 1) {
            addMultipleNumsRow(row, numsInRow, centerIds);
        }
        else if (numsInRow.size() == 1){
            addSingleNumRow(row, numsInRow.get(0), centerIds);
        }
    }

    private void connectRows(ConstraintSet conSet, int[] centerIds) {
        conSet.connect(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                       centerIds[0],
                       ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

        for (int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS - 1; ++row) {
                conSet.connect(centerIds[row],
                               ConstraintSet.TOP,
                               centerIds[row + 1],
                               ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
            }

        conSet.connect(centerIds[NUM_OF_ROWS - 1],
                       ConstraintSet.TOP,
                       ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.TOP);
    }

    private void connectAndChainRow(int[] rowButtonIds,
                                    int centerId,
                                    ConstraintSet conSet) {
        // First button will be attached to the left side of the parent
        conSet.connect(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                       rowButtonIds[0],
                       ConstraintSet.LEFT);

        for (int col = 0; col < rowButtonIds.length - 1; ++col) {
            conSet.connect(rowButtonIds[col],
                           ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                           rowButtonIds[col + 1],
                           ConstraintSet.LEFT);

            if (rowButtonIds[col] != centerId) {
                conSet.connect(rowButtonIds[col],
                               ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                               centerId,
                               ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
            }
        }

        if (rowButtonIds[rowButtonIds.length - 1] != centerId) {
            conSet.connect(rowButtonIds[rowButtonIds.length - 1],
                           ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                           centerId,
                           ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        }

        // Connecting to the right side of the parent
        conSet.connect(rowButtonIds[rowButtonIds.length - 1],
                       ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                       ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                       ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

        conSet.createHorizontalChain(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                     ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                     ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                                     ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                     rowButtonIds,
                                     null,
                                     ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);
    }

    private void addMultipleNumsRow(int row,
                                    List<Integer> numsInRow,
                                    int[] centerIds) {
        mButtonIds[row] = new int[numsInRow.size()];

        for (int pos = 0; pos < numsInRow.size(); ++pos) {
            int col = numsInRow.get(pos);
            Button button = createButton(row, col);

            button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                     ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            int currButtonId = button.getId();
            mButtonIds[row][pos] = currButtonId;
            mScreenLayout.addView(button);

            if (pos == 0) {
                centerIds[row] = currButtonId;
            }
        }

        Log.i(logTag, "Created constrain chain and buttons for row: "
                      + row + " number of columns: "
                      + numsInRow.size());
    }

    private void addSingleNumRow(int row,
                                 int num,
                                 int[] centerIds) {
        Button button = createButton(row, num);
        button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mScreenLayout.addView(button);

        mButtonIds[row] = new int[1];
        mButtonIds[row][0] = button.getId();

        centerIds[row] = button.getId();
    }

    private Button createButton(int row, int col) {
        Button resButton = new Button(this);

        resButton.setTextAlignment(Button.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        resButton.setText(String.format("(%d, %d)", row, col));

        resButton.setId(View.generateViewId());

        return resButton;
    }
}
```